# Kivy, Detecting tilt device in Android

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How to determine the angle of the phone orientation on Android by using kivy.  i tried `Window.bind(on_flip=self.checkFlip)` but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Do you really need the actual angle? If not, you could try binding to the `size` property of the `Window` or your top level `Layout`, and examine the height and width to determine whether you are in landscape or portrait mode.

Comment: ooh thanks u but i think i need something like sensor to tell if a device is tilted (am trying to do a  platformer racing game but i want to control the car by tilting the device instead of swiping left and right.

Comment: ooh thanks u but i think i need something like sensor to tell if a device is tilted (am trying to do a  platformer racing game but i want to control the car by tilting the device instead of swiping left and right.

Comment: I think there is no simple solution. My guess is that you would have to use `pyjnius` to access the Android java classes on your phone.

Comment: I was just doing some other research and stumbled upon `Plyer`. I think that may fit your needs. It does the `pyjnius` magic for you. It can be installed using `pip`.

Comment: thank you john i found that too. thank you so much